# Can't import SVG in Gatsby TypeScript Project - Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am trying to use svg files in my Gatsby TypeScript project. I am making use of [gatsby-plugin-react-svg](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-svg/), and the error I see on the app is

```
One unhandled runtime error found in your files. See the list below to fix it:


Error in function createFiberFromTypeAndProps in ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25058
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `IndexPage`.
```

[image]

I leveraged the information mentioned in [Error while using SVG in Gatsby Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64780769/error-while-using-svg-in-gatsby-typescript)

I have reproduced the error in the repository linked below

https://github.com/hhimanshu/gatsby-svg-import-example

Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the including rule as a string:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
  options: {
    rule: {
      include: `/svg/`
    }
  }
}
```

Note the backticks: `` `/svg/` `` instead of `/svg/`

Comment: Hello @Ferran, that doesn't work either :(

Comment: I've cloned your repo and I've spotted the issue; there's no issue regarding the SVG (you can add it in the `IndexPage` and it renders properly. The source of the issue comes from the `Header`, which is exported as default because of the stories but imported as a named module. Leaving the import as `import Header from '../components/header';` works, despite there's something odd in the `Header` exportation tbh

Comment: Hey @Ferran, do you have a patch, branch so that I can look at the diff?

Comment: https://github.com/hhimanshu/gatsby-svg-import-example/pull/1

Comment: For more details, please refer to https://github.com/hhimanshu/gatsby-svg-import-example/pull/1#issuecomment-946753345. 
This contains continuation of our discussion. Thanks

Comment: Hey @ferran, it does to an extent. It still doesn't work with storybook, but I will consider it a separate issue. I will accept this answer now.
I have pinged you on Github with Storybook issue separately. Thanks for all the help